# Convert a formatted date string to a date value in XPath

Tags: date, xpath, date-parsing

How can I convert a date contained in a string into a date value with XPath?

I got the string by formatting a date value with `fn:format-date`, and now I want the date value from the formatted string.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

You can use EXSLT's `date:date(string)`. It is implemented in most XSLT processors but also as a pure XSLT function.

Documentation: http://www.exslt.org/date/functions/date/index.html.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it says in your link that the date/time string specified as an argument must be a string in the format defined as the lexical representation of either xs:dateTime in  or xs:date. If the argument is not in either of these formats, date:date returns an empty string (''). But my string date format is DD/MM/YYYY . Does it make a problem ? If it does how can i change the accepted date format?

Comment: There is `date:parse-date()` but it unimplemented in most processors. Your best bet is to tokenize the date yourself, put it back in the required format and then then use `date:date()` to get a xs:date object. See http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/extensions/functions/analyze-string.xml for a starting point on how to read pieces of date from a date string.