# Comparing dates in Xpath with different formats

Tags: xpath, selenium-ide

I have a date in this format `"21-Mar-2014"`

I already tried to search for `Xpath` formulas but with no use

I am getting the first format `21-Mar-2014` using `SeleniumIDE` and want to check if this value is the date of today,
So how can xpath generate today's date and compare it for the date extracted using Selenium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse the string into a date with an xpath function such as `date:date(string)` (described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208959/convert-a-formatted-date-string-to-a-date-value-in-xpath) question).

Today's date already in xml date format is supplied by `fn:current-date()` (see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp#context))

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value, sore it in a variable, and then compare it. Eg:

```
storeText   //xpath/goes/here                              myDate
storeEval   (new Date(storedVars['myDate']) > new Date())  isAfterToday
```

Note, the `storedVars` array holds all the variables.
`new Date` should parse most formats, otherwise you can use any javascript in the `storeEval` stage to reformat it.